# (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral

Tags: node.js, forever

When we run the packaged unit tests in node-modules forever,
We got this "(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral."

This is warning only and this warning does not occur all the times. This only shows up when we invoke the tests using a jenkins server.
If we run the npm test directly on the machine, we did not see such issues.

I saw many posting about this warning but no one explain the root cause of it?

Could this be a timing related issue?

Comment: The cause may be that the services that handle the jenkins and the events that execute your test over use process.nextTick . process.nextTick is going to be changed or deprecated. Maybe the server has a newer version of node than you, so the problem is that "your version" does not show you the warnings. So verify if you code abuse of process.nextTick, and when you upgrade your node version make sure that you replace each one of them for setInmediate when corresponds.

Comment: The node version is identical.  I am aware of the deprecation of process.nextTick. The tests that we executed are the unit tests of forever. I think may be more I should post a question to the forever owner..